# du disk caching - why is this disk faster on one machine than another?

Tags: mount, hard-disk, ext4, cache

If I plug an external hard drive into a RasberryPi4, and run:
`time du -sh /mnt/disk/thisfolderis300gb.dir`

Then it takes about 6 minutes, all subsequent runs also take 6 minutes,

But if I plug the same HDD into my ageing linux laptop, and run the same command, it also 6 minutes on the first run, but all subsequent runs take only **2 seconds.**

Clearly some sort of caching is at work here.  What exactly is happening here, and how can I get the same "performance" on the RPi? (I tried copying the mount options, no effect)

I note that neither device comes close to running out of ram.

**Hardware Details:**
Hard drive: External 2.5" 2TB USB3, ext4.
RaspberryPi4: 4GB Ram, USB3.
Aging Laptop: 6 years old+, 16GB ram, linux mint, only USB2.

RaPi mount options: `(rw,relatime)`
Linux mint mount options: `(rw,nosuid,nodev,uhelper=udisks2)`

*I have tried mounting on the RaPi with both the above mount options, the result is the same.

**Laptop `/proc/meminfo`, before running du**

```
MemTotal:       16386892 kB
MemFree:        11127292 kB
MemAvailable:   13237468 kB
Buffers:          192568 kB
Cached:          2331040 kB
SwapCached:            0 kB
Active:          3166152 kB
Inactive:        1523380 kB
Active(anon):    2166896 kB
Inactive(anon):   312204 kB
Active(file):     999256 kB
Inactive(file):  1211176 kB
Unevictable:          96 kB
Mlocked:              96 kB
SwapTotal:       2097148 kB
SwapFree:        2097148 kB
Dirty:               124 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:       2166040 kB
Mapped:           918028 kB
Shmem:            314208 kB
KReclaimable:     238016 kB
Slab:             377336 kB
SReclaimable:     238016 kB
SUnreclaim:       139320 kB
KernelStack:       15360 kB
PageTables:        38840 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:    10290592 kB
Committed_AS:   10813140 kB
VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:       42604 kB
VmallocChunk:          0 kB
Percpu:             6208 kB
HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB
AnonHugePages:         0 kB
ShmemHugePages:        0 kB
ShmemPmdMapped:        0 kB
CmaTotal:              0 kB
CmaFree:               0 kB
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
Hugetlb:               0 kB
DirectMap4k:      362240 kB
DirectMap2M:    16404480 kB
```

**Laptop `/proc/meminfo`, after running du**

```
MemTotal:       16386892 kB
MemFree:         8264124 kB
MemAvailable:   12752864 kB
Buffers:         1291636 kB
Cached:          2430124 kB
SwapCached:            0 kB
Active:          4706588 kB
Inactive:        1605828 kB
Active(anon):    2591628 kB
Inactive(anon):   346244 kB
Active(file):    2114960 kB
Inactive(file):  1259584 kB
Unevictable:          96 kB
Mlocked:              96 kB
SwapTotal:       2097148 kB
SwapFree:        2097148 kB
Dirty:              5784 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:       2590316 kB
Mapped:           949516 kB
Shmem:            348248 kB
KReclaimable:    1452468 kB
Slab:            1595388 kB
SReclaimable:    1452468 kB
SUnreclaim:       142920 kB
KernelStack:       16544 kB
PageTables:        45964 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:    10290592 kB
Committed_AS:   12123736 kB
VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:       43836 kB
VmallocChunk:          0 kB
Percpu:             6208 kB
HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB
AnonHugePages:         0 kB
ShmemHugePages:        0 kB
ShmemPmdMapped:        0 kB
CmaTotal:              0 kB
CmaFree:               0 kB
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
Hugetlb:               0 kB
DirectMap4k:      376576 kB
DirectMap2M:    16390144 kB
```

**RasPi4 `/proc/meminfo`, before running du**

```
MemTotal:        3999784 kB
MemFree:         3828048 kB
MemAvailable:    3789780 kB
Buffers:           14584 kB
Cached:            51556 kB
SwapCached:            0 kB
Active:            48208 kB
Inactive:          32684 kB
Active(anon):      14984 kB
Inactive(anon):     8336 kB
Active(file):      33224 kB
Inactive(file):    24348 kB
Unevictable:          16 kB
Mlocked:              16 kB
HighTotal:       3264512 kB
HighFree:        3189372 kB
LowTotal:         735272 kB
LowFree:          638676 kB
SwapTotal:        524284 kB
SwapFree:         524284 kB
Dirty:                 4 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:         14792 kB
Mapped:            19408 kB
Shmem:              8576 kB
Slab:              34932 kB
SReclaimable:      14160 kB
SUnreclaim:        20772 kB
KernelStack:        1072 kB
PageTables:         1108 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:     2524176 kB
Committed_AS:      85956 kB
VmallocTotal:     245760 kB
VmallocUsed:           0 kB
VmallocChunk:          0 kB
Percpu:              608 kB
CmaTotal:         262144 kB
CmaFree:          222908 kB
```

**RasPi4 `/proc/meminfo`, after running du**

```
MemTotal:        3999784 kB
MemFree:         3274908 kB
MemAvailable:    3742736 kB
Buffers:          428308 kB
Cached:            37832 kB
SwapCached:            0 kB
Active:           254960 kB
Inactive:         227440 kB
Active(anon):      16504 kB
Inactive(anon):     8336 kB
Active(file):     238456 kB
Inactive(file):   219104 kB
Unevictable:          16 kB
Mlocked:              16 kB
HighTotal:       3264512 kB
HighFree:        3200564 kB
LowTotal:         735272 kB
LowFree:           74344 kB
SwapTotal:        524284 kB
SwapFree:         524284 kB
Dirty:                 0 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:         16284 kB
Mapped:            19976 kB
Shmem:              8580 kB
Slab:             185740 kB
SReclaimable:     158128 kB
SUnreclaim:        27612 kB
KernelStack:        1056 kB
PageTables:         1172 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:     2524176 kB
Committed_AS:      89956 kB
VmallocTotal:     245760 kB
VmallocUsed:           0 kB
VmallocChunk:          0 kB
Percpu:              608 kB
CmaTotal:         262144 kB
CmaFree:           51616 kB
```

Comment: How much RAM on ageing laptop?

Comment: What is the output of `cat /proc/meminfo` before and after on each machine?

Comment: Thankyou, have posted as requested.  Buffers increases approx 1.2gb on the laptop, approx 600mb on the pi - neither device comes close to running out of ram though.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is, you guessed it caching.

How to improve caching: more RAM.

- Stop running processes that use a lot of RAM.
- Get more RAM (The Pi is maxed out, so not an option).

Comment: Thankyou.  Though perhaps there is another cause?  Neither machine comes close to running out of ram. The pi has approx 3.5gb free. `free -h` shows the `du` command uses about 1.2gb of cache on the laptop, and about 600mb on the Pi. I don't know why one is half the other, nor why caching doesn't work on the pi - there is plenty of ram left...